# Cursor in sqlite remaining in -1 position

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I am coding for an android app, I have 3 columns in my database, I have put values into the database using a cursor and I want to retrieve those and display it. But while retrieving it i am getting an exception i.e. ***CursorIndexOutofBounds Exception, index -1 requested with a size of 1***. During debugging i realized that the cursor pointer is not moving at all, even after using methods like moveToFirst(), moveToNext(), it remains in -1 position. Here's my code

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TableLayout t1=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        TableRow tr_head=new TableRow(this);
        tr_head.setId(TableRow.generateViewId());
        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView label_bus=new TextView(this);
        label_bus.setId(TextView.generateViewId());
        label_bus.setText("BUS");
        label_bus.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_bus.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_bus);

        TextView label_arrival = new TextView(this);
        label_arrival.setId(TextView.generateViewId());
        label_arrival.setText("Expected Arrival Time");
        label_arrival.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_arrival.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_arrival);

        TextView fare = new TextView(this);
        fare.setId(TextView.generateViewId());
        fare.setText("Fare");
        fare.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        fare.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(fare);
        t1.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        try {
            databaseHelper.addFriend("C23", "5 mins", "10");
            databaseHelper.addFriend("DN46", "7 mins", "10");
            databaseHelper.addFriend("C8A", "2 mins", "10");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception Caught"+e);
        } 

        MyDatabaseHelper ob=new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
        ob.getFriends().moveToNext();
        int a;
        String b;
        a=ob.getFriends().getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("No. of columns "+a);
        a=ob.getFriends().getCount();
        System.out.println("No. of rows "+a);
        b=ob.getFriends().getColumnName(2);
        System.out.println("The column is "+b);

        boolean c;

        String BUS="",Expected_Arrival_Time="",f="";
        if(ob.getFriends()!=null) {
            System.out.println("Something is present");
            c=ob.getFriends().moveToFirst();
            System.out.println("The truth value is "+c);
            a=ob.getFriends().getColumnIndex("BUS");
            System.out.println("The index of BUS "+a);
            a=ob.getFriends().getColumnIndex("Expected_Arrival_Time");
            System.out.println("The index of expected arrival time "+a);
            a=ob.getFriends().getColumnIndex("Fare");
            System.out.println("The index of Fare "+a);
            System.out.println(ob.getFriends().getCount());
            a=ob.getFriends().getPosition();
            System.out.println("The position of the cursor is "+a);
            c=ob.getFriends().moveToNext();
            System.out.println("Truth value of c "+c);
            a=ob.getFriends().getPosition();
            System.out.println("The position of the cursor is "+a);

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView labelBUS = new TextView(this);
            labelBUS.setText(BUS);
            labelBUS.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr.addView(labelBUS);

            TextView labelARRIVAL = new TextView(this);
            labelARRIVAL.setText(Expected_Arrival_Time);
            labelARRIVAL.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr.addView(labelARRIVAL);

            TextView labelFARE=new TextView(this);
            labelFARE.setText(f);
            labelFARE.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tr.addView(labelFARE);

            t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            if(!ob.getFriends().moveToNext())

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**MyDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Bus_Database";

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) 
    {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE busdb (BUS TEXT, Expected_Arrival_Time TEXT, Fare INTEGER);");
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS busdb");

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addFriend(String BUS,String Expected_Arrival_Time,String fare) throws SQLException
    {
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues(3);

        values.put("BUS", BUS);

        values.put("Expected_Arrival_Time", Expected_Arrival_Time);

        values.put("fare",fare);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("busdb","BUS",values);
    }

    public Cursor getFriends()
    {
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().query("busdb",new String[] { "BUS", "Expected_Arrival_Time", "Fare"},null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.out.println("Something is present");
    c=ob.getFriends().moveToFirst();
    System.out.println("The truth value is "+c);
    a=ob.getFriends().getColumnIndex("BUS");
    System.out.println("The index of BUS "+a);
    a=ob.getFriends().getColumnIndex("Expected_Arrival_Time");
    System.out.println("The index of expected arrival time "+a);
    a=ob.getFriends().getColumnIndex("Fare");
```

Every time you call `getFriends()` method you are getting new Cursor.
So it is obvious that you can't do nothing with it.
Save your cursor in some variable and then work with it.

```
Cursor friendsCursor = ob.getFriends();
if (friendsCursor != null) {
    friendsCursor.moveToFirst();
    // you code
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for responding ... my cursor is now moving but now i am having an exception of out of memory ... @Anatol

Comment: Try to ask a fresh SO question and post your problematic code.
I am not so good in memory questions, so maybe other people will help you.